# Transfer all root mail to the anough user

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I want to transfer my root mail to another user (his nick's `userto`).
I do not want to forward mail, because of `userto`'s home directory locate at encryption HDD which I mount when I use it and dismount when I don't use it. Therefore if I will forward mail to `userto` they will lose if the HDD will not mount. And I don't need it, because root mail has a system message.

I wanted to transfer mail via command line when I need it.

I have set PostFix and DoveCot (mailbox).

I have tried to use `dovecot` but it hasn't let me get access to root mail.
For check I use `doveadm search -u root ALL`.

I have had an error:

```
Error: Invalid settings in userdb: userdb returned 0 as uid
doveadm
Error: User lookup failed: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

Maybe I need to use other tools that `dovecot`.

I only see one way, to create a new user (with nick's `collectmail`) and forward all mail from root to his mailbox. And from `collectmail` move mail to `userto` via command line when I need. But I don't think then that way is the best.

**EDIT:**

IMO I don't use `spool`.

I have mailboxes and all mail puts into `~Mailbox`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try copying them from root's directory to user's directory? Generally root's mail is stored in `/var/mail`

First, check the location where the root's mail is stored by

```
sudo env | grep MAIL
```

It is generally `/var/mail/root` or `/var/spool/mail/root`

Second, check the user's mail location by: `env | grep MAIL`
It is also should be: `/var/mail/$USER` or `/var/spool/mail/$USER`

Now, just simply try copying them from root to $USER with root privilege.

Comment: I use mailboxes, therefore all mail puts into `~Mailbox/` I do not use `spool`.

Answer (score 0):

If You, like me, just want to be able to read the root mails with dovecot (without the drawbacks involved with forwarding or copying them to another user), the best solution for me is to create a dedicated user for this purpose with a binfs-mounted Maildir, for example:

```
apt install bindfs
useradd -c "Account to Read ROOT mails with Dovecot" -M -r -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d /nonexistent -U rootmail
mkdir /var/spool/mail/mboxes/rootmail
chown rootmail: /var/spool/mail/mboxes/rootmail
echo -e '\n/var/spool/mail/mboxes/root /var/spool/mail/mboxes/rootmail fuse.bindfs map=root/rootmail:@root/@rootmail 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
mount /var/spool/mail/mboxes/rootmail
```

Wit that setup You can use the user rootmail to access mail with IMAP client utilizing dovecot server (Probably You have to configure dovecots first_valid_uid=1 and first_valid_gid=1 to allow for system users or add the user as non-system-user omitting the `-r` flag to useradd).